# v2ray and connect to a proxy server

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy

i want to use a squid proxy to make a http proxy between 2 servers.
one of my vps(num 1) is in iran (centos 7) and another one(num 2) is other country.
i was installed squid proxy on vps 2 and v2ray on vps 1.
i configure v2ray outbound like this :

```
{
  "log": {
    "loglevel": "warning", 
    "access": "./access.log"
  },
 
  "api": {
    "services": [
      "HandlerService",
      "LoggerService",
      "StatsService"
    ],
    "tag": "api"
  },
  "inbounds": [
    {
      "listen": "127.0.0.1",
      "port": 62789,
      "protocol": "dokodemo-door",
      "settings": {
        "address": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "tag": "api"
    }
  ],
  "outbounds": [
    {
      "protocol": "vmess",
      "settings": { 
        "vnext": [
          {
            "address": "1.1.1.1",
            "port": 8888,
            "users": [
              {
                "alterId": 64,
                "id": "b12614c5-5ca4-4eba-a215-c61d642116ce"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "tag": "VMESS",
      "proxySettings": {
          "tag": "HTTP"  
        }
    },
    {
      "protocol": "http",
      "settings": {
        "servers": [
          {
            "address": "my ip vps2",
            "port": 3128,
            "users": [
              {
                 "user": "username", 
                 "pass": "password" 
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "tag": "HTTP"
    }
  
,
    {
      "protocol": "freedom",
      "settings": {}
    },
    {
      "protocol": "blackhole",
      "settings": {},
      "tag": "blocked"
    }
  ],
  "policy": {
    "levels": {
      "0": {
        "statsUserUplink": true,
        "statsUserDownlink": true
      }
    },
    "system": {
      "statsInboundDownlink": true,
      "statsInboundUplink": true
    }
  },
  "routing": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "inboundTag": [
          "api"
        ],
        "outboundTag": "api",
        "type": "field"
      },
      {
        "ip": [
          "geoip:private"
        ],
        "outboundTag": "blocked",
        "type": "field"
      },
      {
        "outboundTag": "blocked",
        "protocol": [
          "bittorrent"
        ],
        "type": "field"
      }
    ]
  },
  "stats": {}
}
```

but when i create an account in v2ray it doesn't work and failed.
please help me to make a proxy with squid proxy and v2ray script to round censorship internet in iran.
thanks for your helps.

Comment: Just delete the first outbound object that tagged as "VMESS"